# jquery - date calculation

Tags: jquery, date

My question is simple.

```
jQuery('#from').val(jQuery('#to').val());
```

I want to set the `jQuery('#from')` value to `jQuery('#to')` - 28 days.

For now, the format of date is `mm/dd/yyyy`   ex) 04/21/2014

`jQuery('#to').val()` is 04/21/2014

what function should I use to calculate the date?

Comment: show us your attempts

Answer (score 4):

use good old js:

```
 var fromDate = new Date($('#from').val() );
 var toDate = new Date();
 toDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 28);
 $('#to').val(toDate.toString())
```